# displaying the received no

Tags: c

```
#include <reg51.h>
#include "_LCD_R8C.c"
#define INPUT_LENGTH 11

char input[INPUT_LENGTH];  /* The input from the serial port */
int  input_pos = 0;       /* Current position to write in the input buffer */

int main()
{
  int i;

  lcd_init();
  lcd_clear();
  SCON = 0x50;
  TMOD = 0x20;                /* timer 1, mode 2, 8-bit reload */
  TH1 = 0xFD;                /* reload value for 2400 baud */
  TR1 = 1;
  TI = 1;
  RI = 1;
  while (1 == 1)
  {
    /* read the next character from the serial port */
    input[input_pos++] = getCharacter ();
    /* send it back to the original sender */
    for (i = 0; i <= input_pos; i++)
    {
      lcd_print_b(input[i]);
    }
  }
}

char getCharacter(void)
{
  char chr[INPUT_LENGTH];           /* variable to hold the new character */

  while (RI != 1) {;}
  chr[input_pos++] = SBUF;
  RI = 0;
  return (chr);
}
```

I tried displaying the no's which I am receiving from rs232 which is read by the rfreader. 
but I am getting the wrong value on the display i.e 002100 instead of 0016221826. but on the hyper terminal I am  getting the exact correct value with a $ included at the satrting i.e $0016221826.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you really need to adopt a sane indention style, this code is very hard to read.
The problem with your code is that you read an array of user input into a local array "chr", then return the address of that array to main, instead of a character. main() does not expect an address, it expects a character. And regardless of that, the array "chr" is invalid once you have left the function anyhow.

Your printing for loop is also incorrect and doesn't make any sense. You keep printing all characters, over and over, each time you receive a new one.

There might be other issues with the hardware or MCU, I just fixed the most obvious software bugs.

```
#include <reg51.h>
#include "_LCD_R8C.c"

#define INPUT_LENGTH 11


int main()
{
  char input[INPUT_LENGTH];  /* The input from the serial port */
  int  input_pos  = 0;       /* Current position to write in the input buffer */

  lcd_init();
  lcd_clear();

  SCON = 0x50;
  TMOD = 0x20;                /* timer 1, mode 2, 8-bit reload */
  TH1  = 0xFD;                /* reload value for 2400 baud */
  TR1  = 1;
  TI   = 1;
  RI   = 1;

  while(1)
  {
    /* read the next character from the serial port */
    if(input_pos < INPUT_LENGTH)    /* check for buffer overflow */        
    {
      input[input_pos] = getCharacter();
      lcd_print_b(input[input_post]);  /* only makes sense to print each character once */
      input_pos++;
    }
 }


 char getCharacter (void)
 {
   char chr          /* variable to hold the new character */

   while (RI != 1) 
     ;

   chr = SBUF;
   RI = 0;

   return(chr);
 }
```

Comment: @Lundin I am sending the address, is it so? please will you explain me in detail

Comment: @Lundin can i use some delay in ms to receive the characters?

Comment: @Lundin i am getting the display as 255. not $0016221826

Comment: @pradeep `can i use some delay in ms to receive the characters?` Yes. Use on-chip hardware timers. `i am getting the display as 255` Since that is all zeroes (0xFF) it sounds like a bug related to the rs232 hardware configuration. I don't know this MCU (Renesas?) all that well, so I can't help you there.

Comment: but $0016221826 no i can read it on hyper terminal with same rs232

Comment: @pradeep You are _receiving_ characters on the MCU, you are not sending anything out from it. So anything you see on a PC terminal is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Lundin I am receiving chars on MCU then y cant i put them on lcd?